# Why does VIM say there are trailing characters on this command?

Tags: command-line, unix, vim, vi, vimrc

I am trying to write a beautify CSS command in vim that sorts and alphabetizes all of the CSS properties as well as checks to see if there is not a space after the colon and inserts one.

Here is my code:

```
nnoremap <leader>S :g#\({\n\)\@<=#.,/}/sort | %s/:\(\S\)/: \1/g<CR>
:command! SortCSSBraceContents :g#\({\n\)\@<=#.,/}/sort | %s/:\(\S\)/: \1/g
```

These work independently. However, I am trying to pipe them into one command.

On save VIM says:

```
Error detected while processing /var/home/jesse-atkinson/.vimrc:
line  196:
E488: Trailing characters
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to replace your `|` characters in that line with `<bar>`.

What's happening is that Vim is executing that line as separate commands rather than creating a mapping from the whole line.

See: `:help map_bar`

Answer (score 4):

You might have used `#` for comments inside .vimrc whereas you should use `"` instead.

#### Example

In this ~/.vimrc file, the first line is the right way:

```
" Correct comment
# Incorrect comment
```

The second line (the wrong way) results in this message:

```
line    2:
Trailing characters: Incorrect comment: # Incorrect comment
```

#### Solution

Start comments in `.vimrc` with `"` instead of `#` then the messages should go away.